# In AngularyJs, why is my ng-model value not setting the selected option?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ngmodel

I have a select with 4 options. The value is set on `ng-init` and can only be changed by the user from that point. All my initial functions accept the value set by the `ng-init` and change the value works but the selected value isn't showing.

```
<select name="resultShow" class="result-show" ng-init="resultShow=25" ng-change="updateProd(resultShow,prodState,prodType,prodStyle,prodBrand,keywords)" ng-model="resultShow">
    <option value="25">25</option>
    <option value="50">50</option>
    <option value="75">75</option>
    <option value="100">100</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Are you receiving any errors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because select will add a default option if the model's viewValue doesn't match with one of the values present in options of select.

viewValue of `resultShow = 25` is 25 with number data type.

At present select can bind to values of data type string. Thus there is a mismatch. In order to make it work we need to make viewValue of resultShow as 25 with string data type

```
ng-init ="resultShow = '25'"
```

will populate the select dropdown. But the datatype will be changed.

As a workaround, please try $scope.resultShow = 25 in your controller. That will solve the problem.

Additionally, select will automatically remove the added empty option once the viewValue is resolved.

Comment: Added the quotes and it solved the issue. Seems obvious now. lol

Answer (score 0):

check this function. I am using `ng-change` to detect the change. Inside which I am simply logging the value of `resultShow` and I can see its getting the selected option value.

[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/HB7LU/23570/)